Why Does DocuSign Composite Template Reassign My Recipient IDs and How Can I Force It to Use My Defined IDs?
I'm using DocuSign's composite templates to create an envelope with multiple documents and recipients. However, I’ve noticed that DocuSign reassigns the recipientId values I define in my template. This is causing issues because I rely on these recipientId values for further processing in my application.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
{
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this document 4",
  "status": "created",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "9d32b230-574b-4d34-b6cd-86409c70beda"
        }
      ],
       "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "stanley+3@example.com",
                "name": "Applicant Stanley",
                "recipientId": "5",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "signer1",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels"
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "name1",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                      "value": "James Author"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "stanley+2@example.com",
                "name": "CCApplicant Stanley",
                "recipientId": "6",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "signer2",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels"
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "name2",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                      "value": "Akin Dayo"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "stanley+1@example.com",
                "name": "Advisor Stanley",
                "recipientId": "7",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "signer3",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels"
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "name3",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                      "value": "Frank Bisi"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "2",
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNCjMgMCBvYmoNPDwvVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0L1N1YnR5cGUvRm9ybS9CQm94WzAgMCAyODUuMzMzMzEgNTIuMzMzMzFdL0xlbmd0aCAwPj5zdHJlYW0NCgplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag01IDAgb2JqDTw8L1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdC9TdWJ0eXBlL0Zvcm0vQkJveFswIDAgMjg1LjMzMzM0IDUyLjMzMzMxXS9MZW5ndGggMD4+c3RyZWFtDQoKZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNZyVwWsmRUtv8rRm/w/AWPN/wBW1EaKgplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag1zdGFydHhyZWYNMjIyNjENJSVFT0Y=
",
        "name": "Schwabs Account Openning",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "documentId": "1"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "stanley+3@example.com",
                "name": "Applicant Stanley",
                "recipientId": "5",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "signer1",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels"
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "name1",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                      "value": "James Author"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "stanley+2@example.com",
                "name": "CCApplicant Stanley",
                "recipientId": "6",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "signer2",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels"
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "name2",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                      "value": "Akin Dayo"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "stanley+1@example.com",
                "name": "Advisor Stanley",
                "recipientId": "7",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "signer3",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels"
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "name3",
                      "anchorYOffset": "-10",
                      "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                      "value": "Frank Bisi"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
      
    }
  ]
}

When I inspect the created envelope, I see that the recipientId values I defined are not preserved. Instead, DocuSign reassigns them to values starting from 1. Here is what i got retrieving recipients -

{
    "signers": [
        {
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "name": "Advisor Stanley",
            "email": "stanley+3@example.com",
            "recipientId": "3",
            "recipientIdGuid": "51d8adfc-40e4-4a67-b3b7-ea10d523737b",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "2f61c637-7f4f-4243-9dd5-29b6436c120c",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "status": "created",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "recipientType": "signer"
        },
        {
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "name": "Applicant Stanley",
            "email": "stanley+2@example.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "recipientIdGuid": "f86295f6-477b-4420-87ea-a6968db2c448",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "82b75347-b055-4c0b-be92-ce9b6f78f469",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "status": "created",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "recipientType": "signer"
        },
        {
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "name": "CCApplicant Stanley",
            "email": "stanley+1@example.com",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "recipientIdGuid": "f249ba2a-9dbc-4a91-b6d1-f857d68d87ba",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "49425b46-e18f-4f46-8b93-35f7b02eb086",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "status": "created",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "recipientType": "signer"
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "seals": [],
    "witnesses": [],
    "notaries": [],
    "recipientCount": "3"
}


This is by design. A helpful guide on how you can track the documents/recipients is available here
Basically you'd need to make an EnvelopeRecipients: List call and an Envelope documents: List call after the Envelopes: Create call.

Thank you, Karan. This works. Listing the recipients and using their assigned recipientId to assign tabs to them is effective. However, I found that adding the roleName to the signer object makes it easier to assign the correct tabs to the recipients.
